# How does one show $S \sim \frac{N^2}{4}(2 \ln(N) - 1) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

So I used some non-rigorous means to show:

$$ S(N)=  \sum_{
\substack{
k,r =1 \\
k \leq r 
}}^N \frac{r}{k} \sim \frac{N^2}{4}(2 \ln(N) - 1) $$

Is this correct? How would one go about proving this?

Comment: Perhaps start with $S(N)=  \sum\limits_{r=1}^N r \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^r \frac1k\right)$

Comment: I am not sure that the $-1$ is the best number even if you got it from $\int x \log_e(x)\, dx$. Using $0$ or something positive looks as if it would be better

Comment: @Henry I got it from $\int_0^z (\int_0^y y/x dx) dy$ Also Turing's answer seems to vindicate me

Comment: $\int_1^y y/x \,dx = y\log(y)$, Try the first few (or many) terms with and without the $-1$ to see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion is quite correct. If we study the series it's like to have

$$1\cdot(1 ) + 2\cdot(1  +\frac{1}{2} ) +\ldots + N\cdot(1  +\frac{1}{2}  +\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{N})$$

Which behaves like $$\sum_{n} n H_n = \frac{1}{4} \left(2 N^2 H_{N+1}+2 N H_{N+1}-N^2-N\right)$$

Asymptotically, we have

$$\sim \frac{1}{4}(-N^2 + 2N^2H_{N+1})$$

Now

$$H_{N+1} \sim \ln(N+1) + \gamma$$

whence we can write

$$\sim \frac{1}{4}N^2(-1 + 2\ln(N+1))$$

Little improvements can be taken.

Comment: I think it is $1\cdot(1) + 2\cdot(1  +\frac{1}{2}) +\cdots + N\cdot(1  +\frac{1}{2}  +\frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{N})$

Comment: Pardon, I wrote too fast! :D

Comment: The $-1$ does not seem to improve the approximation

Comment: @Henry No indeed, we could "go better" with $$\frac{1}{2}N^2\ln(N)$$

Comment: You neglect a proof of the explicit form of the relation $\sum_n n H_n=(......)/4$. This is the meat of this approach and without it your answer seems not that useful....

Comment: @asgeige I neglected the proof because the diligent student can find it basically everywhere online for it is well known in literature. There is non only this site whereon to rely. There are BOOKS!

Comment: @Turing then why not giving a reference? it is notoriously difficult to find a specific formula through google, especially since this harmonic number identities are not that well known as $\sum_k k^{-2} = \zeta(2)$ for example....